# Bolding multiple specific words based on a read in value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to bold specific words based on a string being read into vba code.
I have the string in read into vba and now want to pick out a word or words to bold them.

If the following was read into vba code: The boy ran down the street.

In the above sentence, what code would I use if I wanted to bold just the word boy? What would I use if I wanted to bold the words boy and the?

I have tried the following code but do not know how to modify it to my specific case.

https://code.adonline.id.au/vba-format-text-microsoft-word/

In short, I want code that will read in a string, search that string for x amount of words, and bold said words to be later exported.

Let me know if you need any more details and what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: "and bold said words to be later exported" - text alone has no concept of "bold" etc so a solution here is dependent on *where* you expect to be able to view specific parts of your text in bold.  What exactly will you do *after* you've made the words bold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel is pretty good at formatting whole cells, but it's not very good at formatting parts of cells. One way that I've been able to do this is to turn the text into very basic HTML and then paste the text into a cell. Here's an example.

```
Public Sub BoldCertainWords()

    Dim sSentence As String
    Dim dobj As DataObject

    Set dobj = New DataObject

    sSentence = "The boy ran down the street"

    sSentence = Replace$(sSentence, "boy", "<strong>boy</strong>")
    sSentence = Replace$(sSentence, "the", "<strong>the</strong>")

    dobj.SetText "<html>" & sSentence & "</html>"
    dobj.PutInClipboard

    Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
    Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"

End Sub
```

You need to set a reference to the MS Forms 2.0 library to get the DataObject if you don't already have it.

Note also that case matters. This will bold `the` but not `The`. You could repeat for typical capitalization or get clever with how you find the words and build the HTML string.

Also note that this particular `PastSpecial` method is Worksheet method, not a Range method. You have to select the range first.